# is this function pseudorandom?

Tags: pseudo-random-function

$F_k$ is a PRF , $k\in\{ 0,1\}^n$ , is $H_k(x) = F_{k_1}(x)||F_{k_2}(F_{k_1}(x))$ a PRF?  
 
when $k=k_1||k_2$ , $k_1,k_2\in\{ 0,1\}^n$ and $k\in\{ 0,1\}^{2n}$ are random strings ,
im trying to prove it using the hybrid argument such that :

1. $H_0$ be $F_{k_1}(x)||F_{k_2}(F_{k_1}(x))$
2. $H_1$ be $f_1(x)||F_{k_2}(f_1(x))$ when $f_1$ is a random function
3. $H_2$ be $f_1(x)||f_2(f_1(x))$ when $f_1 , f_2$ are a random functions.

$H_0$ is $H_k(x)$ and the underlying assumption between $H_0$ and $H_1$ is $F_k$ .
$H_2$ is equal to a random function and the underlying assumption between $H_1$ and $H_2$ is also $F_k$  .
im not very sure about it so i’m asking for opinions and suggestions or maybe a counter example for not being a PRF.

Comment: What happens when $F_{k_1}(x_i)$ collides with $F_{k_1}(x_j)$?

Comment: @SamuelNeves , what does that matter if $k_1$  is random ?

Comment: @SamuelNeves i think this matters only if $k_1$ was fixed , then you can modify the PRF for this $k_1$ and then distinguish H from random.

Comment: Are you saying that $k_1$ and $k_2$ are distinct for every query? How are they derived?

Comment: @SamuelNeves no they are not , they are randomly picked at first , lets assume that $F_{k1}(x_i)$ collide with $F_{k1}(x_j)$ , but for which $k_1$? for every k? , since $k_1$ is picked at first at random you never know if they collide.

Comment: @odu9 Your argument seems sound (except in hybrid $H_2$ where there should be two random functions: i.e., $f_1(x)\|f_2(f_1(x))$.)

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer you are right.

Comment: Sound but incomplete. Your final destination, in the hybrid argument, should be something like $H_3(x) = f_3(x)$, where $f_3$ is a random function from $\{0, 1\}^{n}$ to $\{0, 1\}^{2n}$. Now, how does $f_1(x)\|f_2(f_1(x))$ differ from a truly random function, if at all? My previous comment was a hint.

Comment: @SamuelNeves i think we need to show that it differs from a random function with negligible probability and then we can complete the proof.

Comment: @odu9 Yes, correct. Informally, you need to show that as long as there is no collision in the outputs of $f_1$, the output of $H_2$ cannot be distinguished from $H_3$ (i.e., every output from both $f_1$ and $f_2$ is "fresh"). And this happens with the usual birthday bound probability.